# Unload a module in Python

Tags: python, memory-leaks

TL/DR:

```
import gc, sys

print len(gc.get_objects()) # 4073 objects in memory

# Attempt to unload the module

import httplib
del sys.modules["httplib"]
httplib = None

gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects()) # 6745 objects in memory
```

---

**UPDATE**
I've contacted Python developers about this problem and indeed it's [not going to be possible to unload a module](http://bugs.python.org/issue9072) completely "in next five years". (see the link)

> Please accept that Python indeed does not support unloading modules for severe, fundamental, insurmountable, technical problems, in 2.x.

---

During my recent hunt for a memleak in my app, I've narrowed it down to modules, namely my inability to **garbage collect** an unloaded module. Using **any** method listed below to unload a module leaves thousands of objects in memory. In other words - I can't unload a module in Python...

The rest of the question is attempt to garbage collect a module somehow.

Let's try:

```
import gc
import sys

sm = sys.modules.copy()  # httplib, which we'll try to unload isn't yet 
                         # in sys.modules, so, this isn't the source of problem

print len(gc.get_objects()) # 4074 objects in memory
```

Let's save a copy of `sys.modules` to attempt to restore it later.
So, this is a baseline 4074 objects. We should ideally return to this somehow.

Let's import a module:

```
import httplib
print len(gc.get_objects()) # 7063 objects in memory
```

We're up to 7K non-garbage objects.
Let's try removing `httplib` from `sys.modules`.

```
sys.modules.pop('httplib')
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects()) # 7063 objects in memory
```

Well, that didn't work. Hmm, but isn't there a reference in `__main__`? Oh, yeah:

```
del httplib
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects()) # 6746 objects in memory
```

Hooray, down 300 objects. Still, no cigar, that's way more than 4000 original objects.
Let's try restoring `sys.modules` from copy.

```
sys.modules = sm
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects()) # 6746 objects in memory
```

Hmmm, well that was pointless, no change..
Maybe if we wipe out globals...

```
globals().clear()
import gc # we need this since gc was in globals() too
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects()) # 6746 objects in memory
```

locals?

```
locals().clear()
import gc # we need this since gc was in globals() too
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects()) # 6746 objects in memory
```

What the.. what if we `imported` a module inside of `exec`?

```
local_dict = {}
exec 'import httplib' in local_dict
del local_dict
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects())  # back to 7063 objects in memory
```

Now, that's not fair, it imported it into `__main__`, why? It should have never left the `local_dict`... Argh! We back to fully imported `httplib`.
Maybe if we replaced it with a dummy object?

```
from types import ModuleType
import sys
print len(gc.get_objects())  # 7064 objects in memory
```

Bloody.....!!

```
sys.modules['httplib'] = ModuleType('httplib')
print len(gc.get_objects())  # 7066 objects in memory
```

Die modules, die!!

```
import httplib
for attr in dir(httplib):
    setattr(httplib, attr, None)
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects())  # 6749 objects in memory
```

Okay, after all attempts, the best is +2675 (nearly +50%) from starting point... That's just from one module... That doesn't even have anything big inside...

Ok, now seriously, where's my error? 
How do I unload a module and wipe out all of it's contents?
Or is Python's modules one giant memory leak?

Full source in simpler to copy form: http://gist.github.com/450606

Comment: 1. Have you ever examined, one by one, what exactly are the remaining objects? 2.ou are trying to test using "python's" modules. Have you tried the same approach with a naive big module created by you? a module that does not reference anything outside itself?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python does not support unloading modules.

However, unless your program loads an unlimited number of modules over time, that's not the source of your memory leak.  Modules are normally loaded once at start up and that's it.  Your memory leak most likely lies elsewhere.

In the unlikely case that your program really does load an unlimited number of modules over time, you should probably redesign your program. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it does load reasonably unlimited number of modules - it's a web app server that accepts new revisions of it's own source code and reloads it (that's pretty standard web task). The leak IS from the fact that old code is still out there in memory, even if replaced, even if unreachable...

Comment: Python does support unloading modules.  They're garbage collected, like every other object in Python.

Comment: @Slava: You might want to take a look at the source code to `mod_python`, which has its own importer that is designed to handle reloading modules without producing memory leaks. There may be some code in there that you could use.

Comment: @David: Isn't `mod_python` is written in C?

Comment: @Glenn: they are garbage collectable objects, yes.  So are True and False.  Can you get the reference count down to 0?  Not so easy.  See also: http://bit.ly/9mvndb

Comment: @Daniel: as sad as it to accept - it seems that you are right about "Python does not support unloading modules". Thanks

Comment: @Slava (3 comments up): partly, but not entirely. There is a lot of Python code in it too, including the importer. See [the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/quetzalcoatl/mod_python/trunk/lib/python/mod_python/importer.py?view=markup).

Comment: I explained the reference count issue: it's tricky and usually not worth it.  My problem is, as I said, that Python *does* support unloading modules.  That's not a nitpick; it's an important implication of Python's modules that people should understand: module references are just like any other object references.  (Yeah, native libraries are an annoying exception.)

Comment: The `sys.modules.copy()` does create a reference, but even if I remove (or not create at all) this reference (and all others, even using `globals().clear()` and `locals().clear()` and `for key in module: setattr(module,key,None)`) - there are still thousands of stray objects in memory. That's what the question is about. I know the `sys.modules.copy()` and `sys` are references, I did remove them, the objects aren't gone. So, Daniel is right. Thanks for the attempt, though, to both of you.

Comment: @David: great link to mod_python's importer! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I can not find an authoritative perspective on this in python3 (10 years later) (now `python3.8`). However, we can do better percentage-wise now.

```
import gc
import sys

the_objs = gc.get_objects()
print(len(gc.get_objects())) # 5754 objects in memory
origin_modules = set(sys.modules.keys())
import http.client # it was renamed ;)

print(len(gc.get_objects())) # 9564 objects in memory
for new_mod in set(sys.modules.keys()) - origin_modules:
    del sys.modules[new_mod]
    try:
        del globals()[new_mod]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    try:
        del locals()[new_mod]
    except KeyError:
        pass
del origin_modules
# importlib.invalidate_caches()  happens to not do anything
gc.collect()
print(len(gc.get_objects())) # 6528 objects in memory
```

only increasing 13%. If you look at the kind of objects that get loaded in the new `gc.get_objects`, some of them are builtins, source code, `random.*` utilities, `datetime` utilities, etc. I am mostly leaving this here as an update to start the conversation for @shuttle and will delete if we can make more progress.

Comment: Appreciate the effort here! Very interesting to see the percentage change

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about Python, but in other languages, calling the equivalent of `gc.collect()` does *not* release unused memory - it will only release that memory if/when the memory is actually needed.

Otherwise, it makes sense for Python to keep the modules in memory for the time being, in case they need to be loaded again.

Comment: The problem is that I need to replace them with new versions. And even when I replace it 1-to-1 with same size module - the memory usage grows (leaks)... Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 6):

`Python's small object manager rarely returns memory back to the Operating System.` From [here](https://rushter.com/blog/python-memory-managment/) and [here](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/). So, stricktly speaking, python has (by design) a kind of memory leak, even when objects are "gc collected".

Answer (score 0):

(You should try to write more concise questions; I've only read the beginning and skimmed the rest.)  I see a simple problem at the start:

```
sm = sys.modules.copy()
```

You made a copy of sys.modules, so now your copy has a reference to the module--so of course it won't be collected.  You can see what's referring to it with gc.get_referrers.

This works fine:

```
# module1.py
class test(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print "unloaded module1"
a = test()

print "loaded module1"
```

.

```
# testing.py
def run():
    print "importing module1"
    import module1
    print "finished importing module1"

def main():
    run()
    import sys
    del sys.modules["module1"]
    print "finished"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

module1 is unloaded as soon as we remove it from sys.modules, because there are no remaining references to the module.  (Doing `module1 = None` after importing would work, too--I just put the import in another function for clarity.  All you have to do is drop your references to it.)

Now, it's a little tricky to do this in practice, because of two issues:

- In order to collect a module, all references to the module must be unreachable (as with collecting any object).  That means that any other modules that imported it need to be dereferenced and reloaded, too.
- If you remove a module from sys.modules when it's still referenced somewhere else, you've created an unusual situation: the module is still loaded and used by code, but the module loader doesn't know about it anymore.  The next time you import the module, you won't get a reference to the existing one (since you deleted the record of that), so it'll load a second coexisting copy of the module.  This can cause serious consistency problems.  So, make sure that there are no remaining references to the module before finally removing it from sys.modules.

There are some tricky problems to use this in general: detecting which modules depend on the module you're unloading; knowing whether it's okay to unload those too (depends heavily on your use case); handling threading while examining all this (take a look at imp.acquire_lock), and so on.

I could contrive a case where doing this might be useful, but most of the time I'd recommend just restarting the app if its code changes.  You'll probably just give yourself headaches.

Comment: Well, not to be snyde, but you should've read the question, or at least the word "completely" in title (or at least the tags). The problem isn't that I wan't to reload, the problem is *memory leak* associated with any (listed) kind of module removal (including ones that you proposed, which *are* listed in my question, along with dozen others). 

Actually I added `sys.modules.copy()` at a very late stage, removing it doesn't change anything (try yourself).

Comment: The source, to try: http://gist.github.com/450606 . Try removing the sys.modules.copy and you'll see that still there's more than 50% increase in objects even with all references to module removed.

Comment: See here for short of what's wrong (using your code): http://gist.github.com/450726 . I don't try to load-unload `sys`, since we're operating on `sys.modules`, so I use `httplib` - you can try any other.

Comment: To clarify: `httplib`, which I try to unload - is not in `sys.modules` yet, when I create a copy.

Comment: +1 for "You'll probably just give yourself headaches."