# Remove an imported python module

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unload a module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105801/unload-a-module-in-python)

After importing Numpy, lets say I want to delete/remove numpy import reference

```
import sys 
import numpy as np 

doMe()
   np.something()

#unimport np
#remove numpy from memory
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/487718/1107807

Comment: Zaur, you would need to do that if you need to downgrade a package for different functionality.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Unloading a module from Python [is not supported](http://bugs.python.org/issue9072).

Comment: `del sys.modules["moduleName"]`
`del moduleName`

Comment: Thanks @Miladiouss. That worked for me.

Comment: It may have worked in one instance, but [this article](https://justus.science/blog/2015/04/19/sys.modules-is-dangerous.html) explains why it should be discouraged and can catastrophically break things.

Comment: So, the conclusion is that you should NEVER change your software once you write it?  Write it absolutely correctly the first time so that you never have to change it?  Debugging software is for amateurs?  That makes NO sense!  Instead of telling people what NOT to do, why not tell people how they SHOULD replace an old version of a module with a new version?

Comment: @JDMorgan No. That's not the conclusion. Just restart the process. Simples.