# Unloading a module in Python 3.x (not the same as re-loading)

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's clear to me that there was no clean solution in Python 2 to unload a module, and this was a known bug, that was set to be corrected.

The posts:

[How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module/487718)
[Remove an imported python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781257/remove-an-imported-python-module)

of the year 2009 and 2010 confirm this lack of support for unloading a module.

I wonder if this was solved in Python 3.x. When I do, `import os`, `del os`, `dir()`, the `os` module is not there (at least not visible, usable). Is it gone?

Comment: `import os; del os; assert 'os' not in dir()` also holds in Python 2.

Comment: OK, that would be the wrong way of knowing whether the memory has been freed.

Comment: Check `sys.modules`, not `dir`.

Comment: @poke. I have already linked to that page. I am asking whether it's still uptodate. The answers there relate to Python 2.x, I asked about Python 3.x.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Yeah, I got that link from you. The same situation still applies though. The module caching is by design. Also, in that question, the second answer refers to Python 3.

Comment: @poke: but they explain how to re-load, not how to un-load (which is the bug in Python 2, and appears to be in Python 3 too).

Comment: @QuoraFeans It’s not a bug. It’s *by design*. You can’t completely unload modules.

Comment: @poke It's bad design and you're wrong: completely unloading pure-Python modules is [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487718/2809027). Completely unloading a top-level module `foo`, for example, reduces to `del sys.modules['foo']; del foo`. **That's it.** Completely unloading submodules is slightly more involved, but not really. Completely unloading C extensions, however, appears to be infeasible.

Comment: this is not a duplicate .... importlib has no "unload" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sys.modules` does still hold a reference to the module.

```
>>> import six
>>> del six
>>> sys.modules["six"]
<module 'six' from '/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/six.py'>
```

sys.modules still holds a reference. So I don't think you can unload a module in Python 3.3 either.

Comment: You _can_ [unload modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487718/2809027), but you didn't even really try. Since `six` is a top-level pure-Python module, unloading `six` reduces to **(A)** `del sys.modules['six']` and **(B)** `del six` (in either order). That's it. Deleting all references to that module results in that module being garbage collected.

Comment: @CecilCurry Why not make that an answer?