# How would one go about "un-importing" a SINGLE module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

Just out of curiosity, how would one go about *`un-importing`* a module?

For example, you import a couple of modules like this:

```
import x, y, z
```

Then say for some reason you don't want and / or need module `y` to be included anymore, how would you **only** *`un-import`* module `y` without affecting modules `x` or `z`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [You don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105801/unload-a-module-in-python)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but if your code doesn't refer to module y any more you would just do: import x, z basically this is just shorthand for import x import y import z

Comment: The only thing you can do is to throw away the reference with `del y` but there's no real unloading involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> Import statements are executed in two steps: (1) find a module, and initialize it if necessary; (2) define a name or names in the local namespace (of the scope where the import statement occurs).

If you need a module temporarily and you are concerned about cluttering the global namespace you can import in a local scope and the global namespace won't be affected.

AFAIK, the first step of the `import` statement cannot be undone.

Comment: Thank you for your time & help, I appreciate it, +1.