# Why is the time to load python modules so variable?

Tags: python, python-import, timing

I am trying to speed up a command line Python script I wrote.
In the process of profiling, I noticed that the time to load the various libraries I am importing at the top is very variable.
The modules I am currently importing are:

```
import os
import urllib2
import datetime
import dateutil.rrule as rr
import netCDF4
from pylab import *
import glob
import cookielib
import traceback
import base64
from scipy import interpolate
import dateutil.parser as dparser
```

And when I time just those imports from the command line, I get very variable results, from  minimum of ~2.7 seconds ( which seems pretty long already just to load the above-mentioned modules) to ~8 seconds

```
$ time python -c "import mycode.py"

real    0m2.763s
user    0m0.239s
sys 0m0.104s

$ time python -c "import mycode.py"

real    0m8.852s
user    0m0.224s
sys 0m0.157s
```

So, 2 questions:

- is there a way to reduce the time to perform those imports
- if not, is there a way to ensure the time to import remains the lowest of the above numbers

Comment: FYI -- "snippet" support is for JavaScript that can be run in a browser (see https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ for an understanding of the context; it's basically an alternative to JSFiddle, and intended to be used only in situations where JSFiddle otherwise would be). Use the `{}` button to code-format code in other languages.

Comment: What's in `merra2Player`? `import merra2Player` may not just be running the imports shown.

Comment: ...with respect to the question, though -- the big question marks are pylab, scipy and netCDF4. Assuming this isn't an embedded system or otherwise a highly resource-constrained device, I'd almost place money that it's one of the three that's your primary culprit (since the others are builtins, and otherwise well-known). A good [mcve] would actually provide exact steps for someone else to reproduce the problem -- isolating the specific modules at fault.

Comment: Given how much bigger `real` is than `user` or `sys`, this may be due to other activity on your machine, or factors like what's in the disk cache.

Comment: Yup -- smells like block cache to me too.

Comment: Charles, thanks for the info.        Ignore "merra2Player", it's just the name of the code  which contains those imports.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,   a minimal and reproducible code would simply consist of putting the above imports in a file called mycode.py, and from the command line, running  `time python -c "import mycode.py" `, wouldn't it ?

Comment: It's not "minimal" if it includes a bunch of modules that *don't* substantively increase time to load alongside the ones that do. Which is to say, once this is brought down to a MCVE it's likely to be a more specific question, like "why does scipy sometimes take so long to load?".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989235/accurate-timing-for-imports-in-python/43995651?s=3|0.0000#43995651

Comment: ok, thanks for the comments. I'll do some further tests and report here if I find something relevant.